# UNIX: how to translate "/" when using search and replace command by sed

Tags: unix, sed

```
path=/tmp/a1

file=/tmp/a1/a.txt

file_without_path=`echo $file | sed s/'\/tmp\/a1'/''/g`

echo $file_without_path
```

In the code above, I have a question

If variable "path" is a dynamic veriable which allows users to self-define

e.g., user defines "path" as /usr/local/

Then I pass this value to do search and replace

However, if I pass this value without any intervention

the program may treat it as `echo $file | sed s//usr/local/''/g`

I tried to use `tr -s '/' '\/'` but it is not successful

I would like to ask how can you solve such case

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The separator for the `sed` "s" command is not required to be `/`; sed will use as separator whatever comes after "s":

```
sed s%'/tmp/a1'%''%g  ## no need to worry about escaping slashes any more
```

Comment: Glad to hear it. You may consider accepting the answer if it does solve your problem. ;)